# Hide and unhide cursor with tput

Tags: terminal, escape-characters, tput

```
tput civis
```

successfully hides the cursor.

```
tput cvvis
```

should unhide it, but it doesn't.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Try `tput cnorm` instead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the ncurses [terminal database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html#download_database), `cvvis` is used as documented in the terminfo manual page:

```
   cursor_visible            cvvis  vs   make cursor very
                                         visible
```

and if there is no difference between *normal* and *very visible*, the `cvvis` capability is usually omitted.  The feature is used in `curs_set`:

> The **`curs_set`** routine sets the cursor state  to  invisible,
>   normal, or very visible for visibility equal to `0`, `1`, or `2`
>   respectively.  ***If*** the terminal supports the visibility re-quested, the previous cursor state is returned; otherwise,
>   `ERR` is returned.

The [`terminfo(5)`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Highlighting_-Underlining_-and-Visible-Bells) manual page also says

> If the cursor needs to be made more  visible  than  normal
>   when it is not on the bottom line (to make, for example, a
>   non-blinking underline into an easier  to  find  block  or
>   blinking underline) give this sequence as `cvvis`.  If there
>   is a way to make the  cursor  completely  invisible,  give
>   that as `civis`.  The capability `cnorm` should be given which
>   undoes the effects of both of these modes.

Some terminal descriptions may (incorrectly) equate `cvvis` and `cnorm`, since some emacs configurations assume that `cvvis` is **always** set.