# Cursor disappears when running `top -n1 | head`

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, top, cursor

When running

```
top -n1 | head
```

the terminal's cursor disappears.
Running `top -n1` brings it back.

Tested in `gnome-terminal` and `tilix` in Ubuntu 16.04 and CentOS 7.5.

---

Running `top -n1 | tail` doesn't have this issue, so I think, something at the end of `top` output let the cursor reappear which is not executed when printing the `head` only.

What causes this and how can I get back the cursor more elegantly ?

Comment: I can also get it back with running `tput cnorm`. ([via](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220330/hide-and-unhide-cursor-with-tput))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wasn't able to recreate this behavior everywhere, but it does show up on Ubuntu 18.04

---

It is instructive to examine hex dumps of the top output:

```bash
$ top -n1 | head -n1 | xxd
00000000: 1b5b 3f31 681b 3d1b 5b3f 3235 6c1b 5b48  .[?1h.=.[?25l.[H
00000010: 1b5b 324a 1b28 421b 5b6d 746f 7020 2d20  .[2J.(B.[mtop - 
00000020: 3133 3a34 333a 3034 2075 7020 3120 6d69  13:43:04 up 1 mi
00000030: 6e2c 2020 3120 7573 6572 2c20 206c 6f61  n,  1 user,  loa
00000040: 6420 6176 6572 6167 653a 2030 2e38 312c  d average: 0.81,
00000050: 2030 2e35 342c 2030 2e32 321b 2842 1b5b   0.54, 0.22.(B.[
00000060: 6d1b 5b33 393b 3439 6d1b 2842 1b5b 6d1b  m.[39;49m.(B.[m.
00000070: 5b33 393b 3439 6d1b 5b4b 0a              [39;49m.[K.
$ top -n1 | tail -n1 | xxd
00000000: 1b5b 3f31 326c 1b5b 3f32 3568 1b5b 4b    .[?12l.[?25h.[K
$
```

In particular, the sequences starting `0x1b5b3f` are [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Escape_sequences), which effectively are meta-data to control things like cursor position and text colour.

In particular, towards the start of the first line of top output, there is `ESC [?25l`, and towards the end of the last line is `ESC [?25h`.  As per the wikipedia page, these are the respective codes to hide and show the cursor.

By piping the `top -n1` output to `head`, the terminal will receive the hide-cursor command at the start, but not the show-cursor command at the end, and hence the cursor will remain invisible until some other action turns it on again.

@MrShunz suggestion to use the `-b` option to `top` is right on.  This option disables all of the ANSI escape sequences in top's output, instead just outputting plain ASCII printable text.  No cursors will be harmed during the execution of `top` with `-b`:

```bash
$ top -b -n1 | head -n1 | xxd
00000000: 746f 7020 2d20 3133 3a35 393a 3236 2075  top - 13:59:26 u
00000010: 7020 3138 206d 696e 2c20 2031 2075 7365  p 18 min,  1 use
00000020: 722c 2020 6c6f 6164 2061 7665 7261 6765  r,  load average
00000030: 3a20 302e 3134 2c20 302e 3036 2c20 302e  : 0.14, 0.06, 0.
00000040: 3037 0a                                  07.
$
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. The behavior can be reproduced with `printf \\033[?25l` to hide and `printf \\033[?25h` to reveal the cursor again. The other escape sequences`[H` and `[2J` clear the terminal (compare `clear | xxd`)

Answer (score 17):

Best way IMHO is to make `top` use "batch" mode (`-b` flag) which is intended to be used with non-interactive use cases such as piping to another program or to a file.

So, this

```
top -n1 -b | head
```

won't be leaving the shell without a cursor.

As for the *why the cursor disappears*...

Since `top` is an interactive program, it "messes" with the terminal in order to grab input, scroll content, etc, and it *hides* the cursor.

When terminating it has to restore the cursor and the display status it found before being called, and it does so by sending one or more *control codes* to the terminal itself.

By piping the command through `head`, this control code won't get through (`head` prints just the first 10 lines by default, and the output of both `top` and the control codes to restore the terminal state is always >10 lines).

In fact, if you give `head` enough lines to print, the cursor appears!

For example,

```
top -n1 | head -n 100
```

leaves a cursor on my system.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Using `-b` is the way to go for me.